# Blazor WASM: Multiple client apps

Tags: blazor-webassembly, .net-5

I'm working on a Blazor WASM app and I want to add an Administration. The administration will use a completely different set of css and js files so I want to create a new client application for it.

What I'm trying to achieve is to have my app on address https://myapp.com and the admin part on http://myapp.com/admin.

I'm following the example provided in this response https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/21872 but it doesn't work so far. The main application loads, but when I try to navigate to the administration I'm getting 404.

Has anyone did it with .net5?

Answer (score 1):

The problem I was facing was caused because I forgot to add a dependency of the second client project into the server project.